# openerp: using the value of a variable in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

```
abe= []
abibiti=1
self.cr.execute("SELECT name FROM account_analytic_account where parent_id=abibiti")                
for t in self.cr.fetchall():
for item in t:
    abe.append(item)
```

I want to use the value of variable "abibiti"  to check in the where clause , can anyone help me

Comment: openerp displays this message:  column "abibiti" does not exist
LINE 1: ...T name FROM account_analytic_account where parent_id=abibiti

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue with the way you wrote the query in the cr.execute. Please change it to:

```
abe= []
abibiti=1
cr.execute("SELECT name FROM account_analytic_account where parent_id=%s"%(abibiti))                
for t in cr.fetchall():
    for item in t:
        abe.append(item)
```